Multiple SQL statements wrapped inside NVL function
I have the two below queries (that are used as an inline view I join to in a larger query) that I am using UNION in order to fetch a record from either table where it exists.
To be more efficient, I essentially want to query the first SQL statement and if it returns a record then there is no need to query the 2nd SQL statement (after UNION).
(SELECT * FROM 
       (SELECT A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
              ,C.SUBINVENTORY_CODE,
              to_char(B.TRANSACTION_COST,'FM99990.90') TRANSACTION_COST
              ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID, C.SUBINVENTORY_CODE ORDER BY A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID, B.COST_DATE DESC) rownum1                               
            ,'' SECONDARY_INVENTORY
          FROM CST_ONHAND_V A,
               CST_ITEM_COST_HISTORY_V B,
               CST_TXN_LAYER_DTLS_V C
          WHERE 1=1
             AND A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID= :p_inv_num
             AND A.REC_TRXN_ID=B.TRANSACTION_ID                       
             AND A.COST_ORG_ID = B.COST_ORG_ID
             AND A.COST_BOOK_ID = B.COST_BOOK_ID
             AND A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID=B.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID                           
             AND A.REC_TRXN_ID=C.REC_TRXN_ID                             
         ORDER BY B.COST_DATE DESC NULLS LAST
     )
    WHERE rownum1 = 1 AND TRANSACTION_COST IS NOT NULL 
    
    UNION   
    
    SELECT * FROM 
    ( SELECT INV.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID,           
        SEC.SECONDARY_INVENTORY_NAME  SUBINVENTORY_CODE,        
        NVL(to_char((LN.UNIT_PRICE / UOM.CONVERSION_RATE),'FM99990.90'),to_char(LN.UNIT_PRICE,'FM99990.90')) TRANSACTION_COST 
        
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY INV.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID , decode(substr(SEC.SECONDARY_INVENTORY_NAME,1,3),
                                                              '70O','70OPR'
                                                              ,'70M','70OPR'
                                                              ,SEC.SECONDARY_INVENTORY_NAME ) 
   ORDER BY INV.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID, SEC.SECONDARY_INVENTORY_NAME ) rownumber
         ,INV.SECONDARY_INVENTORY 
    FROM INV_ITEM_SUB_INVENTORIES INV
       ,inv_secondary_inventories SEC 
         ,PO_LINES_ALL LN
        ,PO_HEADERS_ALL HDR
        ,INV_UOM_CONVERSIONS UOM                     
 
        
    WHERE SEC.ASSET_INVENTORY = 2
       AND SEC.SECONDARY_INVENTORY_NAME = INV.SECONDARY_INVENTORY
     AND SEC.organization_id = INV.organization_id
      AND LN.ITEM_ID = INV.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
      AND (LN.EXPIRATION_DATE IS NULL OR LN.EXPIRATION_DATE > sysdate)
       AND (HDR.END_DATE IS NULL OR HDR.END_DATE > sysdate)
      AND LN.LINE_STATUS <> 'CANCELED'
      AND HDR.PO_HEADER_ID = LN.PO_HEADER_ID
      AND HDR.type_lookup_code = 'BLANKET'
      AND UOM.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID(+) = INV.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
      AND UOM.UOM_CODE(+) = LN.UOM_CODE
      AND INV.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = :p_inv_num
      AND SEC.attribute1='Y'
  )
    WHERE rownumber = 1 
) TC
   

I tried wrapping both of these statements inside an NVL function as below but it is erroring:
SELECT * FROM 
             NVL( (  (SELECT A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
                      ,C.SUBINVENTORY_CODE,
                      to_char(B.TRANSACTION_COST,'FM99990.90') TRANSACTION_COST
                      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID, C.SUBINVENTORY_CODE ORDER BY A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID, B.COST_DATE DESC) rownum1                               
                    ,'' SECONDARY_INVENTORY
                  FROM CST_ONHAND_V A,
                       CST_ITEM_COST_HISTORY_V B,
                       CST_TXN_LAYER_DTLS_V C
                  WHERE 1=1
                     AND A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID= :p_inv_num
                     AND A.REC_TRXN_ID=B.TRANSACTION_ID                       
                     AND A.COST_ORG_ID = B.COST_ORG_ID
                     AND A.COST_BOOK_ID = B.COST_BOOK_ID
                     AND A.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID=B.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID                           
                     AND A.REC_TRXN_ID=C.REC_TRXN_ID                             
        ORDER BY B.COST_DATE DESC NULLS LAST
        )
        WHERE rownum1 = 1 AND TRANSACTION_COST IS NOT NULL ) ,
    
    --UNION   
    
(   SELECT * FROM 
    ( SELECT INV.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID,           
        SEC.SECONDARY_INVENTORY_NAME  SUBINVENTORY_CODE,        
        NVL(to_char((LN.UNIT_PRICE / UOM.CONVERSION_RATE),'FM99990.90'),to_char(LN.UNIT_PRICE,'FM99990.90')) TRANSACTION_COST 
        
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY INV.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID , decode(substr(SEC.SECONDARY_INVENTORY_NAME,1,3),
                                                              '70O','70OPR'
                                                              ,'70M','70OPR'
                                                              ,SEC.SECONDARY_INVENTORY_NAME ) 
    ORDER BY INV.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID, SEC.SECONDARY_INVENTORY_NAME ) rownumber
         ,INV.SECONDARY_INVENTORY 
    FROM INV_ITEM_SUB_INVENTORIES INV
       ,inv_secondary_inventories SEC 
         ,PO_LINES_ALL LN
        ,PO_HEADERS_ALL HDR
        ,INV_UOM_CONVERSIONS UOM                     
 
        
    WHERE SEC.ASSET_INVENTORY = 2
       AND SEC.SECONDARY_INVENTORY_NAME = INV.SECONDARY_INVENTORY
     AND SEC.organization_id = INV.organization_id
      AND LN.ITEM_ID = INV.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
      AND (LN.EXPIRATION_DATE IS NULL OR LN.EXPIRATION_DATE > sysdate)
       AND (HDR.END_DATE IS NULL OR HDR.END_DATE > sysdate)
      AND LN.LINE_STATUS <> 'CANCELED'
      AND HDR.PO_HEADER_ID = LN.PO_HEADER_ID
      AND HDR.type_lookup_code = 'BLANKET'
      AND UOM.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID(+) = INV.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
      AND UOM.UOM_CODE(+) = LN.UOM_CODE
      AND INV.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = :p_inv_num
      AND SEC.attribute1='Y'
  )
    WHERE rownumber = 1 ) 
)  )

If there is a more efficient way of executing the 2nd statement conditionally based on whether the first statement returns NULL I am happy to hear feedback on that also. Thanks!
EDIT:
Nick additional info: @MT0 I like this idea but not sure if it will work as I am using these queries as an inline view.
SELECT *
FROM MyTable1
, (SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT column1 , column2, ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY B.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID, C.SUBINVENTORY_CODE ORDER BY B.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID, B.COST_DATE DESC) rownum1 , 1 AS priority
    FROM SubTable1 B,
         SubTable2 C
    WHERE B.TRANSACTION_ID = C.REC_TRXN_ID
   ORDER BY B.COST_DATE DESC NULLS LAST   )
  WHERE rownum1 = 1 
 UNION
   SELECT * FROM
      (SELECT INV.column1, SEC column2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY INV.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID , SEC.SECONDARY_INVENTORY_NAME ) 
         ORDER BY INV.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID, SEC.SECONDARY_INVENTORY_NAME ) rownum1 , 2 AS priority
        FROM SubTable1 INV,
             SubTable2 SEC
        WHERE IOQD.item_id = SEC.item_id   ) 
WHERE rownum1 = 1  ) ORDER BY priority FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES

Because of the UNION placed out the outer inline view I'm not sure if I can still reference the priority column and use FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES ? Any thoughts?

The first statement returns 0...n rows of 5 values each. What would "returns NULL" even mean in this context?

I'm not following your comment "returns 0...n rows of 5 values each" Can you clarify what you mean?

There is a reason for the M in [mre] ....

@Nick Your statement returns a resultset with multiple columns and possibly multiple rows. Each value in each row can be NULL or not but there is no concept of the whole set being NULL - the closest thing that comes to my mind is the result being empty (i.e. contains no rows).

Pure SQL has no way to determine if a query should be executed or not.  If this is really the best direction, I would look at a stored procedure.

I can not invoke a stored procedure, this is a proprietary tool that I can query the database only, it does support CTEs though.

So I take it the NVL function can NOT interpret a NULL result set from a query (as I have tried doing above), and really is only able to check for NULL at the column level only? I really just wanted to avoid running the 2nd query all-together if the first query fetches a record to avoid unnecessary processing.

You can add an extra column to your UNION query that determines the priority of the rows and then, from Oracle 12, can ORDER BY priority FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES to get only those rows with the highest priority.
SELECT q1.*, 1 AS priority
FROM   query1 q1
UNION ALL
SELECT q2.*, 2
FROM   query2 q2
ORDER BY priority
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES

fiddle

I edited my question above trying to use your proposed solution, would appreciate your thoughts...

@Nick Something like fiddle (but there is no sample data so it is untested).

Thank you! For some reason the ORDER BY priority doesn't recognize priority alias in my query as being valid, but it does work if I use the numerical column order value for it i.e ORDER BY 4 (for the 4th column)

Well, there is a way but the query would be large so I recommend to rewrite it with CTE
WITH first_query AS (
    <1st query>
)
SELECT xxx
FROM first_query

UNION ALL

<2nd query>
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM first_query);

The CTE first_query executes 1st query.
The main query is then executed:
Selects from first_query.
Executes the query n2 only if first_query contains no rows, which is enforced by NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM first_query).

This CTE-based approach is efficient and clearly separates each part of the logic while maintaining control over the execution of the second query based on the result of the first query.

Can the CTE be embedded into an inline view, as in the below example?
SELECT '123'
FROM MyTable
, (WITH MyCTE AS (SELECT * FROM (SELECT MyColumn1, MyColumn2)
FROM first_Query_Table) )
UNION
(SELECT Mycolumn1, MyColumn2
FROM 2nd_query_table)

@Nick I don't understand why someone would use this approach, it doesn't make any sense to me. You cannot directly place CTE in inline view as it acts as a temporary table definition and should be at the beginning of SQL. You can use something like WITH cte_example AS (
SELECT column1, column2
FROM table_name
WHERE condition
)
SELECT iv.*
FROM (
SELECT column1, column2
FROM cte_example
WHERE another_condition
) iv;

You could use cursors. Load your first query, for example:
declare found boolean := false;
BEGIN
   FOR your_record IN (
       <your query here>
   )
   LOOP
       found := true;
       <do some stuff>
   END LOOP;
END;

where, in the <do some stuff> part you do your parsing logic and you may also set a boolean variable called found to true and later on you can check whether found is false, which meant the first query was empty and load the second query conditionally into the cursor.
